# Download locations of a custom Google map to an Android device

Tags: android, google-maps, location, customization

I have an application using `Google Maps API`. I've managed to draw `overlays` in my map using fixed coordinates.

Now I want to be able to download custom maps `locations` coordinates (maps created using `My Maps`). I've created a test custom map with two locations and I have its URL: https://maps.google.es/maps/ms?msid=213392682798795757896.0004e10fe92c98f1bcbb9&msa=0

With this URL I can access the map using android's browser, but I want to download the locations' coordinates using my app to draw them to my app's map. Is there any way to obtain them?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the way to do it. I just had to add &output=kml at the end of the URL, like this:

```
https://maps.google.es/maps/ms?msid=213392682798795757896.0004e10fe92c98f1bcbb9&msa=0&output=kml
```

This way the returned data contains all the Placemarks defined in the map.